# Iterate in inner array from json response

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this json response and i want to render **post_comment** field .

**response.json :**

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "tags": [],
    "post_comment": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "author_comment": 45,
            "comment_body": "xgdgfdf",
            "created_date": "2018-06-13T12:55:52.460282Z",
            "post": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "author_comment": 45,
            "comment_body": "asdsasd",
            "created_date": "2018-06-13T13:45:01.535194Z",
            "post": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "author_comment": 45,
            "comment_body": "asdsasdDasdasdasdasdasdadadadadadaaaaaaaaaaaaaadddddddd",
            "created_date": "2018-06-13T13:46:18.721375Z",
            "post": 2
        },

    ],
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/2/",
    "author_name": "",
    "title": "god of war",
    "body": "this is the god of war ..I Fdfwfdwdfound the solution, i just have to tell django to try connecting using the original backend if the user isnt a student or professor. just add 'django.sdfdsdfsfsfsy",

    "slug": "god-of-war",
    "publish_date": "2018-06-12T10:27:07.100113Z",
    "author": 45
}
```

and this is my **postDetailomponent** :

```
class postDetailComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchPostDetail(this.props.match.params.id);

  }

  render(){
    const { post } = this.props;
    if (!post) {
      return <div>loading </div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className='container' >
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
        <h6>{post.publish_date}</h6>
        <h6>{post.tags}</h6>
        <div >


    );

  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { post: state.postDetail.post};
}
```

I tried map through the **post_comment** but it react says :

```
const comments = post.post_comment.map((comment) => <li>{comment.comment_body}</li>);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

so how can I iter in json?my whole point is : all of my data is there and renders correctly but I cant render post_comment cause this is an multi object. even I tried set key to my **comments**  .but did not work correctly.

Comment: can you show your `fetchPostDetail` function

Comment: @Tony function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { post: state.postDetail.post};
}  ... problem is not the post .just inner json object is not rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the maping statement as,

```
let comments=[];
if(this.props.post.post_comment && this.props.post.post_comment.length>0)
  comments = this.props.post.post_comment.map((comment) => <li>{comment.comment_body}</li>);
```

Initially before the api call this props value will be undefined, so handling that condition should solve the problem.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: no . if (this.props.post_comment && this.props.post_comment.length>0){
       comments = post.post_comment.map((comment) => <li>{comment.comment_body}</li>);
    }    . no errors .but not rendering in page with this tag <h6>{comments}</h6>

Comment: How are you passing the props value for post_comment  to this component??

Comment: {post: state.postDetail.post } . so i pass the post with this : const { post } = this.props; . and post renders. look at my code exactly is the same in my project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173295/discussion-between-rohith-murali-and-babak-abadkheir).